# RavenDB Replication: Can I set a database's Raven-Replication-Source Guid manually?

Tags: ravendb, database-replication, failover, disaster-recovery

**EDIT 2:** I'm encountering precisely [the same issue](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ravendb/6aA2jkoz8g4/Sxruy7VKCIMJ).

For RavenDB Replication, the Raven-Replication-Source Guid is very handy when trying to discern which documents came from which server.

But in a disaster recovery scenario, it may be necessary to ensure that an instance's Raven-Replication-Source Guid remains the same as it was before it failed.

My Question:

- Can I set a database's Raven-Replication-Source Guid manually?

---

**EDIT (in response to [Ayende's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16562984/109941)):**

- This is a follow-up question to [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/41803/7259).

And here is the scenario:

- The client uses **one** master RavenDB instance for all of its reads and writes.
- This master instance replicates to a [hot spare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_spare) instance.
- When the master instance fails, the client immediately fails over to the hot spare by virtue of [this configuration setting](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ravendb/px-_aWe6h1Q/LZEpLuI8OtAJ).
- Upon closer inspection, we discover that the master RavenDB instance has been corrupted and needs to be purged.
- When we recreate the master RavenDB instance, replication from the hot spare will **only** replicate documents that were created on the hot spare.

  - Emphasis: The hot spare will not replicate documents that were created on the master (prior to the disaster) back to the master because their Raven-Replication-Source Guid is the master's Raven-Replication-Source Guid.
- And this is a problem because, as I said, the master RavenDB instance was purged, we needed to recreate the database from scratch, and we need to replicate **all** of the documents from the hot spare back to the master instance.

---

**EDIT 3:** [@Ayende's answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16562984/109941) pushed me to discover that I was solving the wrong problem. [Here is the right way](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ravendb/6aA2jkoz8g4/7wKslzbFWaoJ) to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not something that you control.
And I am not sure what scenario you have that requires this. The Raven-Replication-Source is the db id of the last db where this changed (without replication).